# A dry run decorator

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-decorators

I'm trying to write a function decorator that wraps functions.  If the function is called with `dry=True`, the function should simply print its name and arguments.  If it's called with `dry=False`, or without dry as an argument, it should run normally.

I have a toy working with:

```
from functools import wraps
def drywrap(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def dryfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        dry = kwargs.get('dry')
        if dry is not None and dry:
            print("Dry run {} with args {} {}".format(func.func_name, args, kwargs))
        else:
            if dry is not None:
                del kwargs['dry']
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return dryfunc

    @drywrap
    def a(something):
#  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
      print("a")
      print(something)

      a('print no dry')

      a('print me', dry=False)

      a('print me too', dry=True)
```

...but when I put this into my application, the print statement is never run even when `dry=True` in the arguments.  I've also tried:

```
from functools import wraps
def drywrap(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def dryfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        def printfunc(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Dry run {} with args {} {}".format(func.func_name,args,kwargs))   
            dry = kwargs.get('dry')
            if dry is not None and dry:
                return printfunc(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                if dry is not None:
                    del kwargs['dry']
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return dryfunc
```

I should note that as part of my applications, the drywrap function is part of utils file that is imported before being used...

```
src/build/utils.py  <--- has drywrap

src/build/build.py
src/build/plugins/subclass_build.py   <--- use drywrap via "from build.utils import drywrap"
```

Comment: I think there's some indentation messed up here

Comment: indent nicely please.

Comment: "works for me" with your code (and after fixing indentation).

Comment: @SteveJessop crap my head.

Comment: Added the from functools.  Apologies about the indentation; I copy pasted from a working code example and did NOT notice any indentation errors on paste.

Comment: The problem is that while the toy code (first example) works, the code in the application (several hundred lines and I'm not sure how to accurate reduce) does not.

Comment: I can re-ask with stubs of the 3-4 files that use this in the application.

Answer (score 2):

The following github project provides "a useful dry-run decorator for python" that allows checking "the basic logic of our programs without running certain operations that are lengthy and cause side effects."

see https://github.com/haarcuba/dryable

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a solution.

```
def drier(dry=False):
    def wrapper(func):

        def inner_wrapper(*arg,**kwargs):
            if dry:
                print(func.__name__)
                print(arg)
                print(kwargs)
            else:
                return func(*arg,**kwargs)
        return inner_wrapper
    return wrapper

@drier(True)
def test(name):
    print("hello "+name)

test("girish")

@drier()
def test2(name,last):
   print("hello {} {}".format(name,last))
```

But as you can see even when you dont have any arguments you have to give `@drier()` instead of `@drier` .

Note : Using python 3.4.1